# How to determine the area of a polygon in an Image

Tags: c++, math, image-processing, polygon, area

If I am having a convex polygon vertices, then my area calculation in image is not coming accurate by the standard formula.

(For simiplicity) if I am having 3x3 square, and the vertices are (1,1) (1,3) (3,3) (3,1)

[image]

by polygon area calculation method depicted here

[image]

and dividing the summation by 2 we get the Area.

So for the 3 x 3 data above, we'll get area as 4 instead of 9.

[image]

This is happening because vertices are not points but a **pixel**.

this is the corresponding code. The coordinates are cyclic.

```
int X[] = { 1, 1, 3, 3, 1};
int Y[] = { 1, 3, 3, 1, 1};
double Sum1 = 0;
double Sum2 = 0;
int numElements = 5;

    for (int k = 0; k < numElements-1; k++)
    {
        Sum1 += X[k] * Y[k + 1];
        Sum2 += Y[k] * X[k + 1];
    }

    double area = std::abs((double)(Sum1 - Sum2))/2;
```

For square, we can do +1 to width and height and get the area correct. But what about the irregular polygons in the image?
I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: the usual question: what did you try? I suggest you show some code which fails, and give a guess where it fails.

Comment: I understand your supposed algorithm not at all. Most importantly: How exactly do you intend to calculate the area of general polygons? Further: How is the picture related to that? How did you transform the picture into code?

Comment: It seems you get confused with polygon representation. Mentionaed approach works for polygons, defined by vertice coordinates. But you want to define polygon by tile set and use the same formula... If you find coordinates of corners of your polygon and apply this method, you'll get correct results.

Comment: @MBo - I am not saying that the formula is incorrect. When we do the calculation in images, vertices are not points but pixels (having a square area itself).
In the above image if we do corner detection or take convex hull points, we get corners as (1,1) (1,3) (3,3) (3,1). So the area calculation is coming 4 instead of 9.

Comment: @davidhigh- I am using the method mentioned in this link http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon
See area of irregular polygon.

Sum1 += X[k] * Y[k + 1];
Sum2 += Y[k] * X[k + 1];
this is the code representation of the second picture for the formula 
((y2*x1-x2*y1)+......+(yn*xn-1 - xn*yn-1))/2

Comment: Why you are using topleft corners only (or central points of cells)? Take into account exterior border of cells.

Comment: even if i take central or exterior of a pixel, the coordinates value remains the same. See it from the perspective of image processing rather than a simple math problem.

Comment: Sorry, you are mixing approaches. What is an area of single pixel?

Comment: consider w=1 h=1 so area=1sq unit

Comment: OK, and it is area of rectangle (square) with vertice coordinates (i,j)(i+1,j)(i+1,j+1)(i,j+1). For 3-pixel L-shape we can obtain area=3 for 6-vertice rectilinear polygon (0,0)(2,0)(2,1)(1,1)(1,2)(0,2)

Comment: Note that to get exact pixel area for figures with slanted edges, you have to define every pixel on the border, because different methods of drawing could give different results

Comment: 6-vertice rectilinear polygon (0,0)(2,0)(2,1)(1,1)(1,2)(0,2) -  i didn't understand this.
I agree to the slanted edges problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area can be calculated in following steps:

1)   fetching the pixels between the vertices

2)   sorting the pixels by x coordinates *(or y coordinates)*

3)   taking the difference between min and max y coordinates *(or x)* for a particular x *(or y)* value and adding one to the difference

4)   summing up the total difference

**NOTE:** the area might vary *(if there are slanted edges in the polygon)* depending on the line drawing method chosen

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return (((Point*)a)->x() - ((Point*)b)->x());
}


double CalculateConvexHullArea(vector<int> ConvexHullX, vector<int> ConvexHullY)
{
    float Sum1 = 0;
    float Sum2 = 0;
    std::vector<Point> FillPoints;


        for (int k = 0; k < ConvexHullX.size() - 1; k++)
        {
            drawLine(ConvexHullX[k], ConvexHullX[k+1], ConvexHullY[k], ConvexHullY[k+1], FillPoints);
        }

        //sorting coordinates
        qsort(FillPoints.data(), FillPoints.size(), sizeof(Point), compare);

        double area = 0;
        int startY = FillPoints[0].y(), endY = FillPoints[0].y();
        int currX = FillPoints[0].x();


        // traversing x and summing up diff of min and max Y
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < FillPoints.size(); cnt++)
        {
            if (FillPoints[cnt].x() == currX)
            {
                startY = startY > FillPoints[cnt].y() ? FillPoints[cnt].y() : startY;
                endY = endY < FillPoints[cnt].y() ? FillPoints[cnt].y() : endY;
            }
            else
            {
                int diffY = endY - startY + 1;
                area += diffY;
                currX = FillPoints[cnt].x();
                startY = endY = FillPoints[cnt].y();
            }
        }

        return area + endY - startY + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to work with pixel corners as vertices, consider next method (works for simple figures - all convex ones, some concave ones):

[image]

Add additional fake pixel at right side of every right-border pixel, at bottom side of every bottom-border pixel, at right-bottom of right-bottom corner pixel. Here gray pixels are initial, light blues ones - fake.

Comment: I will get a correct answer if i know which all pixels to fake. The ones which you have shaded wont give me right answer which is 5 for this image.